# How can I associate FIG files with Matlab on Windows so that it doesn't open new copy of Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, file-association

Matlab has `FIG` file format, which may contain plots along with data. If I use "Open With" feature on `Windows` and select `matlab.exe` to open `FIG` files, it will run new heavy copy of `Matlab` each time I click the file.

Can I instruct `Matlab`/`Windows` to reuse existing running copy of Matlab to open `FIG` files?

Comment: I can open fig's on the exists session.. Maybe you have multiple installed versions of Matlab?

Comment: Mathworks has addressed this issue in a self-Q/A post on MATLAB Answers: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93468-why-is-a-new-instance-of-matlab-opened-when-i-double-click-on-a-matlab-file-in-windows-explorer-even

Comment: @SardarUsama I don't understand, what is written there.Don't see anything relevant to my question and case. For example, this page http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/associate-mat-files-with-matlab.html contains GUI elements I don't have. Particularly, I don't have `Programs` pane etc.

Comment: @Adiel yes I do

Comment: The link you gave explains about settings in windows control panel, not about Matlab IDE. I would suggest read @Sardar's link carefully, we can not be more detailed than that, without more details from you about the versions, the system behavior, etc.